# How Can I Make and Run GWTTestCase Based Tests with Intellij 12?

Tags: gwt, gwttestcase

I've tried multiple times over a few months now to do this, but I haven't had any luck.  I've found Google's documentation about how to setup GWTTestCase tests via the command line and Eclipse, but nothing about how to do it with IntelliJ.  When I try to excite GWTTestCase tests in IntelliJ like a normal J-unit test, I get a bunch of errors.  I assume that the Google Eclipse plugin is probably doing some sort of magic to make the tests work in Eclipse, so I'm not even sure if what I want to do is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GWTTestCase`s are especial junit tests, because they have to execute some extra stuff like the gwt compiler. This is done automatically, but the compiler needs to know where your `.java` files are (main and tests). So previously to run the test you have to add the `src, test` folders (if you use ant) or `src/main/java, src/test/java` (if your project is a maven one) to the class-path of your launcher.

If you are using the native [GWT](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gwt.html) support in intellij (it was previously called GWT Studio plugin), it should add those folders to the classpath. You can find more info in this [page](http://java.dzone.com/articles/testing-gwt-applications), although it is a bit outdated.

Comment: It looks like the GWT Studio plugin has been dead for quite sometime.  I think the functionality was just rolled into the main Intellij product.  You did point me in the right direction though.  I discovered that if I right click on the TEST SOURCE FOLDER in Intellij, go to new, then "Google Web Toolkit", I have the option to create a new GWTTestCase test.  Thanks!

Comment: Right, that is the traditional name for the gwt support, the link was ok though. updated the comment.